# Using jQuery to replace form inputs with their value

Tags: jquery

Can jQuery be used in order to tranform this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="a1" value="Input value 1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="a2" value="Input value 2" /></td>
        ...
        <td><input type="text" name="a10" value="Input value 10" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

into this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Input value 1</td>
        <td>Input value 2</td>
        ...
        <td>Input value 10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it can. What errors are you getting with the code you have written?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I haven't written any code yet, I'm kind of new to jQuery.

Comment: Try to narrow down your question. Are you screen scraping another website, are you trying to change your own? What attempts have you made?

Comment: The answer you've accepted (boobiq's) has a pretty big issue, see scessor's answer for a (much) better solution. See my comment on that answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, you can use for example:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function()
{
    $(this).parent('td').html($(this).val());
});
```

untested, but that should be enough

Comment: ...and if the value contains HTML special characters?

Comment: While this works, scessor's answer has much better performance, and does not have the problem of having to encode HTML characters.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - The issue that matters is performance; the special characters IMO is somewhat of a red-herring. `$.text()` I assume would have better performance for larger tables. The best answer would specify that `$.html()` should be used if markup should be interpreted, otherwise use `$.text()`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Completely disagree that the special characters are a red herring. That's how we get exploits and security holes. What if I put `<script src="destroy.js"></script>` in a text field and this code is run? What then? We have the tools to prevent that attack vector, why in heaven's name would we **not** use them?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - One, if a person edits an `input` within their browser and puts pure html, there's not much of an exploit there. Two, if the code that is *saved* to a server is allowed to contain such exploits, the problem is *not* the browser. You're getting quite a bit involved in this particular answer; I agree that `$.text()` makes more sense in general, but I don't agree it's due to the encoding issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - And note I do realize in an unsophisticated developer's hands, such as exploit is entirely possible. I just think you're extrapolating more than is evident for this particular answer (in which `$.text()` makes more sense due to performance).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: That's fine. **I** think that if X is the right solution, and someone advocates Y, you should say "wait, X isn't the right tool for this job, Y is." Else, why are we bothering to help the OP? Bad information is worse than no information. Using `html` where you should use `text` ***will*** bite, you, full stop. I'm not particularly "involved" in this answer, I'm just commenting on the answers given (by the time I saw the question, a correct answer had been given and there was no need for me to provide one) and replying when people ask me direct questions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I don't know man, I like to think I'm just as security conscious as anyone, but if we're talking display, we're talking display. If the server provides an exploitable text in such a way, I say that's the server's fault (and the developer's responsibility to mitigate *at the server*). The question was, how to transform a form-based table to a markup-based content table. There are dozens of caveats, the script vector legitimate but IMO not a disqualification. It's just a separate problem if the server provides to a client an exploitable context and action.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: There's no server mentioned in the question. If I put "O'Hara and Co <inc>" in a field for "company name" and click "Save", I expect "O'Hara and Co <inc>" to be shown as a result. If we fail to handle HTML special characters correctly, that won't happen. Is "O'Hara and Co <inc>" a reasonable thing for a user to enter? Maybe, maybe not. But why leave ourselves open to getting it wrong, when it's *so easy* to get it right? Remember that users are, by and large, not sophisticated. They don't know that `<` is in some way special (or `&`, but browsers usually figure that one out).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, and neither was any markup in the input value. If that were me, I'd be stripping anything I didn't want out of that before saving to a database, and if the user wants to enter it locally (in their browser) and affect themselves, I don't know I have any control or desire to control that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: We're talking in circles. I believe that being defensive (**particularly when it costs you nothing**) should be the default choice barring an express design constraint to the contrary, and that the absense of that ethos is a big part of why we have security holes in software. You seem to believe that I'm being over-cautious. So we can just disagree on that. But I'm right. *wink* ;-) *(Last word, if you feel like it, is yours)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I'll let the *old pro* have the last word. `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish: LOL!! ;-) I can't even deny it. Blast.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('td').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).find('input').val());
});
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tqVaj/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I suppose it's not possible that interpreting the HTML instead of encoding it as text may be desirable? I can see the logic of `$.text()`, but I don't think `$.html()` is inherently wrong.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: See my comment on boobiq's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').each(function(){
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.text(elem.find('input[type="text"]').val());
});
```